# How could I increase the width of a column in a tree view?

Tags: view, tree, styles, width, odoo-13

In odoo 13, I have inherited a tree view, and I want to increase the width of a view.
I tried with `style = "width: 120px"` in the `<field>`, but it does not worked.

[click here to see the column to modify the width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txSlF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Luis De la Cruz

**Solution** which doesn't work

> **xml** `<field width="100" />` or `<field style="width: 100" />` or `<field style="width:50 %%" />`

> **xml** `<field class="custom_class" /> ;` with `css .custom_class { width: 1000px;}`

> **xml** : `<field name="custom_field" />` with `css : [data-id="custom_field"]{width: 100px;}`

**Solution** Which Work:

> **xml** : `<tree string="XYZ" class="custom_class"> <field name="custom_field" />`
>
> **css** : `.custom_class [data-id="custom_field"]{width: 1000px;}`

Becuase the `class` `attribute` works on `tree` tag.

Also, you can apply the below thing to increase the `column` width

> `<field name="name" string="    Name    "/>`